# If $\lim_{x\to\infty}u_k(x) = b_k$, how can we show $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_0^\infty u_k(x)=\sum_{0}^\infty b_k$?

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

I am working on a problem from p. 277 of Buck's *Advanced Calculus*. It asks us to prove the following theorem, **without** making the change of variable $x=1/t$:

"Let $ \sum_{1}^\infty u_n(x)$ converge to $F(x)$, uniformly for all $x$ with $c\leq x < \infty$.Let $\lim_{x\to\infty}u_n(x) = b_n<\infty$ for $n=1,2,\dotsc$. Then, $\sum_{1}^\infty b_n$ converges, and $\lim_{x\to \infty}F(x) = \sum_1^\infty b_n$."

(The proof with $x=1/t$ consists of employing the theorem that if $f_n$ are continuous on $\overline{S}$  and converge uniformly on the interior of $S$, then they converge uniformly on $\overline{S}$.)

My idea so far has been to take $N$ such that $\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty u_k(x)<\epsilon$ for all $x\geq c$.  Now I'd like to find $\kappa \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|u_k(x)-b_k|<\epsilon_2 \,\,\,\,\forall k\in \mathbb{Z}^+\,\,\forall x\geq \kappa$. But such a point is not available to me, as far as I know. Any ideas?

Comment: If you let $m_k$ denote the largest $X$ so that $\forall x>X$ :$|u_k(x)-b_k|<\epsilon$, and then we let $M=\text{max}(m_0,m_1,m_2,m_3,...m_n)$. We have that $|u_k(x)-b_k|<\epsilon$, $\forall x>M, k\leq n$.

Comment: Great, so this does give us a point $\kappa$ of the type I was looking for, if we take $N$ as above, and then do your construction for $k<N$

Comment: Typo, it should be chose $X$, not chose the largest $X$; that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Still working on this one. Having the point $\kappa$ helps, but I still can't get it.

Comment: Sorry, the question is not clear for me. Uniformly on $[c,\infty)$ or converge to $F(x)$ pointwise for all $x$ with $c\leq x<\infty$? ('Uniformly' and 'for all' together is confusing.)

Comment: He means uniformly on $[c,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, it is enough to show that the sequence $\left(\sum_{n=1}^Nb_n,N\geqslant 1\right)$ is Cauchy. Fix $\varepsilon>0$, and $N_0$ such that if $M\geqslant N\geqslant N_0$, we have $\sup_{x\geqslant c}\left|\sum_{n=N}^Mu_n(x)\right|<\varepsilon$ (by the assumption of uniform convergence). This gives that for such $M,N$, we have $\left|\sum_{n=N}^Mb_n\right|\leqslant \varepsilon$.

For the second question, fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then take an integer $N$ such that for any $x\geqslant c$,
$$\left|F(x)-\sum_{n=1}^Nu_n(x)\right|<\varepsilon\quad\mbox{and}\quad\left|\sum_{n\geqslant N+1}b_n\right|<\varepsilon.$$
Then for such $x$, 
$$\left|F(x)-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}b_n\right|+\sum_{n=1}^N|u_n(x)-b_n|\leqslant 2\varepsilon,$$
hence 
$$\limsup_{x\to +\infty}\left|F(x)-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}b_n\right|\leqslant 2\varepsilon.$$
As $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we can conclude.

Comment: You say, "Then take an integer $N$ such that for any $x\geqslant c$, $\left|F(x)-\sum_{n=1}^Nu_n(x)\right|<\varepsilon\quad\mbox{and}\quad\left| \sum_{n\geq N+1} b_n\right|<\varepsilon.$" But I think you must mean $x>x_0$ for some $x_0$. Certainly we can't have $\left| F(x) - \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \right|< \varepsilon$ for all $x\geq c$ if $F(c) =1$ and $L=10$, for instance, right?

Comment: I think the issue is that we need to choose $x_0$ such that for all $x>x_0$, $\sum_{n=1}^N (u_n(x) - b_n) < \varepsilon$

Comment: @EricAuld You are right, I missed the term $\sum_{n=1}^N|u_n(x)-b_n|$ in the second line starting from the end. I fixed it, I think.

Comment: But I think there is no way that it can hold for all $x \geq c$, right? Merely for all $x \geq x_0$, some $x_0>c$.

Comment: I just used the definition of uniform convergence on $[c,+\infty)$.

Comment: You say, "for such $x$, (i.e. for $x\geq c$),  
$\,\left|F(x)-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}b_n\right|+\sum_{n=1}^N|u_n(x)-b_n|\leqslant 2\varepsilon$". But this can't be true if (as I say above), $F(c)=1$ and $L=10$, can it?

Comment: In your example, there is no pointwise convergence (it fails at $c$).

Comment: I don't see what that is true. $\sum_1^\infty u_n(x)$ may converge to $1$ at $c$, and yet $\sum_1^\infty b_n = 10$, since that represents the values of $u_n$ as $x\to \infty$.